# rails 3 - query generated with joins getting duplicated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inner-join

I'll be short and to the point.  I am trying to join three tables together to get a total of invoiced hours times the invoiced rate from all **non-archived** clients.  This is what i currently have in my controller:

```
@total_due = Client.find(:all, :joins => [:invoices, :invoice_line_items], :select => "SUM(invoice_line_items.hours * invoice_line_items.rate) as total", :group => "clients.archive, invoices.paid_status HAVING clients.archive = false AND invoices.paid_status = false")
```

My models look like this:

```
# /models/clients.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :invoices
    has_many :invoice_line_items, :through => :invoices
end

# /models/invoices.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    has_many   :invoice_line_items
end

# /models/invoice_line_items.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :invoice
end
```

So, as you can see from the code in my controller i am trying to get the total of all hours times rate for all invoices related to **non-archived** clients, *and* they have not paid yet.  The above code in my controller is duplicating data somewhere because my number is a lot higher than it should be.

The query i am trying to build is this:

```
SELECT SUM(invoice_line_items.hours * invoice_line_items.rate) AS total FROM clients INNER JOIN invoices ON clients.id = invoices.client_id INNER JOIN invoice_line_items ON invoices.id = invoice_line_items.invoice_id GROUP BY clients.archive, invoices.paid_status HAVING clients.archive = false AND invoices.paid_status = false
```

Can someone explain or figure out why i am getting duplicated data in my rails query? I have a feeling it is just joining the tables differently than i am expecting.  I am still fairly new to rails as well.  Thanks!

UPDATE:
This is the query that rails is generating:

```
select sum(invoice_line_items.hours * invoice_line_items.rate) as total
from clients
inner join invoices on invoices.client_id = clients.id
inner join invoices invoices_clients_join on invoices_clients_join.client_id = clients.id 
inner join invoice_line_items on invoice_line_items.invoice_id = invoices_clients_join.id 
group by clients.archive, invoices.paid_status
having clients.archive = false and invoices.paid_status = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i was able to get rails to generate the query i needed by just removing the `invoices` join in my controller.  I guess that combined with the `invoice_line_items` join and the `:through` relationship was making creating many joins.

My controller now looks like this:

```
@total_due = Client.find(:all, :joins => :invoice_line_items, :select => "SUM(invoice_line_items.hours * invoice_line_items.rate) as total", :group => "clients.archive, invoices.paid_status HAVING clients.archive = false AND invoices.paid_status = false")
```

Comment: yea i will, just can't do it for two days since i was the OP :(